# указатель на лямбда выражение c захватом переменных и без

Tags: функции, указатели, лямбда-выражение

Не могу понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было оперировать с указателями на лямбда-выражение с захватом переменных, так же как без захвата переменных? И в третьем примере, почему функции f и f3 нельзя вызвать, но функция f2 вызывается?

```
// первый пример(успешный)
auto  fo = [](void*) ->unsigned {std::cout << 5 << std::endl;  return 0; };
unsigned(*fo2) (void*);
decltype (auto) fo3 = fo;
fo2 = fo;    // компилируется. В чем отличие от второго примера?
fo2(nullptr);// компилируется

fo(nullptr); // компилируется
fo3(nullptr);// компилируется

// второй пример такой же как первый, но с захватом переменных лямбда выражением
auto  foo = [&](void*) ->unsigned {std::cout << 5 << std::endl;  return 0; };
unsigned(*foo2) (void*);
decltype (auto) foo3 = foo;

foo2 = foo;// НЕ компилируется. Почему?

foo(nullptr); // компилируется
foo3(nullptr);// компилируется

// третий пример
auto  *f = &[](void*) ->unsigned {std::cout << 5 << std::endl;  return 0; };
unsigned(*f2) (void*);
decltype (auto) f3 = f;

f2 = *f;// компилируется
f2(nullptr);// компилируется
// как запустить f и f3 ?
f(nullptr);// НЕ компилируется 
*(f(nullptr));// НЕ компилируется
f3(nullptr);// НЕ компилируется
*(f3(nullptr));// НЕ компилируется
```

Answer (score 0):

Захват переменных, это дополнительный аргумент функции. Для компилятора нет возможности переделать лямбда тип на обычный.

```
void f(){
  int x = 5 ;
  auto  foo = [&](void) ->int {++ x ;  return x; };
  foo();
}
```

Лямбда функция в коде реализуется с аргументом  (`$ g++ -std=c++11 -S -Wall -Wpedantic`):

```
[](int**ppx) ->int {++ (**ppx) ;  return **ppx; };
```

Компилятор сам решает, какой способ лямбда реализации создать. И передать этот тип функции не имеет возможности.